# How can I get file binary data out of Git repository using LibGit2Sharp?

Tags: c#, git, gitsharp, libgit2sharp

I have decided to try and migrate my project from using GitSharp to LibGit2Sharp since GitSharp is no longer actively maintained. With GitSharp I was able to access the raw bytes of any file checked into my repo given a branch. I cannot locate any documentation or example code of how this is done using LibGit2Sharp.

Can someone give me and example of how this is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Blob` type exposes a `Content` property that returns a `byte[]`.

The following test in extracted from the **[BlobFixture.cs](https://github.com/nulltoken/libgit2sharp/blob/master/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/BlobFixture.cs#L43)** file and demonstrates usage of this property.

```
[Test]
public void CanReadBlobContent()
{
    using (var repo = new Repository(BareTestRepoPath))
    {
        var blob = repo.Lookup<Blob>("a8233120f6ad708f843d861ce2b7228ec4e3dec6");
        byte[] bytes = blob.Content;
        bytes.Length.ShouldEqual(10);

        string content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
        content.ShouldEqual("hey there\n");
    }
}
```

In this particular test, the Blob GitObject is directly retrieved through the `LookUp()` method. You can also access Blobs from the `Files` property of a `Tree`.

Regarding your more specific request, the following unit test should show you **how to access the raw bytes of a Blob from the tip of a `Branch`**.

```
[Test]
public void CanRetrieveABlobContentFromTheTipOfABranch()
{
    using (var repo = new Repository(BareTestRepoPath))
    {
        Branch branch = repo.Branches["br2"];
        Commit tip = branch.Tip;
        Blob blob = (Blob)tip["README"].Target;
        byte[] content = blob.Content;

        content.Length.ShouldEqual(10);
    }
}
```

**Note:** This test shows another way of accessing a `Blob` (as an abstract `TreeEntry`). Thus, the use of the cast.

Comment: Glad I've been able to help you :)